# How to tell ram size without Lable

Tags: memory

Is possible to tell Ram Size Without seeing Sticker...see only chips(IC's).it is possible or not.

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible.  The part number of the ram can tell you the size.  This picture however will not allow that.

Comment: Google the part number of the individual memory banks, find out their size and multiply the size times the number of banks

Comment: Give me one example for this one

Comment: We can't. Your picture is too low quality to see any useful part numbers. All we can see is that you have 16 chips *on this side* and don't know if there are more chips on the other side.

Comment: yes only 16 chips are there.no chips for other side.

Comment: In that case, as people said, look at the chips and lookup the information for them on the internet. After that you should know the size, which means you will just have to multiply it with the number of chips.

Answer (score 1):

Found via [TinEye Reverse Image Search](https://www.tineye.com/).

Your RAM is the
[4GB 4G DDR2 800MHZ PC2-6400 Computer Memory RAM PC DIMM 240 Pins for AMD ED](http://www.ebay.com/itm/4GB-4G-DDR2-800MHZ-PC2-6400-Computer-Memory-RAM-PC-DIMM-240-Pins-for-AMD-ED-/111867852138?hash=item1a0bd7f56a:g:lDQAAOSwcUBYQAPp).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your image it is impossible to tell you definitively what size that memory stick is because it is too low resolution to be able to read any memory part numbers.

Once you have the part numbers and can find the memory chip size the math is simple, for non-ECC memory. Most memory chips are specified in as Mb or Gb and the small "b" is important as it means that the size is in bits.

All you need is the memory chip size, the number of memory chips, and to then convert from bits to bytes.

Assuming 4gigabit memory chips:

```
16    (chips)
 x
 4    (size as found on data sheet)
 ÷
 8    (bits to bytes conversion)
----
 8 Gigabytes
```